# popup AND a redirection after clicking

Tags: javascript, html

What I'm trying to achieve is to open a popout window with the `windowopen()` function. And at the same time in the main window take the user to another page.

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com/" class="thumbnail" 
    onclick="return !window.open(this.href, 'Google', 'width=500,height=500')"
    target="_blank">
    Link
 </a>
```

So once the user clicks the `Link` I want the popout window to load Google and the original page to navigate the user to `.index.php` any suggestions?

Comment: i dont get it 100% - you mean you want a popup AND a redirection after clicking a link? (just like most of the porn sites?)

Comment: @messerbill yeah that's correct ahaha :3

Comment: `!window.open(this.href, 'Google', 'width=500,height=500')` is not correct. Check the documentation for window.open!

Comment: So maybe `!window.open("http://www.google.com", this.target, 'width=500,height=500')`? And then delete the href attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" class="thumbnail" 
    onclick="window.open(this.href, 'newwindow', 'width=500,height=500');  return true;">
    Link
 </a>
```

Comment: This is what I was after thankyou very much! however is there a way to change the destination of one?

Comment: instead of this.href use domain name in single quotes

Comment: Thankyou! very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works in Chrome and Firefox:

```
<a onClick="window.location='http://www.yahoo.com'" target='_blank' href="http://www.google.com">Click me</a>
```

Pop-ups are automatically blocked by most browsers, so it's probably better to use an href with target set to "_blank"

Answer (score 0):

By using Jquery

```
$(".link").click(function(){
    window.open($(this).attr("href"), "popupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z37vfw91/)